# Targeting specific table tag in table (html)

Tags: html

http://jsfiddle.net/ce1ud8qz/4/

I have been looked it up and I figure I have to use "table:nth=of=type(n)".
However, it does not works in my code.

```css
 .right1:nth-of-type(1){
    color: red;
 }
```

```html
<span class="right1">
  <table class="rightt1">
    <tr>
      <td>first</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>third</td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
</span>
```

I am trying to change each column to different color but I do not know why it doesn't work....
Can anyone give me an advice?

Comment: There is only one column in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the `tr` inside `right1` instead.

```css
.right1 tr:nth-of-type(1){/*or: .right1 tr:first-of-type*/
    color: red;
 }
 
 .right1 tr:nth-of-type(2){
    color: green;
 }
 
 .right1 tr:nth-of-type(3){/*or: .right1 tr:last-of-type*/
    color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<span class="right1">
  <table class="rightt1">
    <tr>
      <td>first</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>third</td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
</span>
```